# Android Jelly Bean issue with SQLite connection

Tags: android, sqlite, database-connection, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a piece of code which access an SQLite database, which works perfectly up until Jelly Bean. In which case not all data is taken from the database ( at least the first column is omitted somehow) 
And also gives the error "unknown error (code 14) could not open database", although some data IS being read from it. 
Do ask for more details if you don't get the situation

Thank you!

```
private class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    public DataBaseHelper() {

        super(myContext, DB_NAME, null, 1);

        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + myContext.getPackageName()
                + "/databases/";
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {

            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {
            // By calling this method and empty database will be created
            // into the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }


    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database does't exist yet.
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just
     * created empty database in the system folder, from where it can be
     * accessed and handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath =DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);

    }
```

Here is the LogCat error

```
     01-11 14:36:32.153: E/SQLiteLog(15050): (14) cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]
     01-11 14:36:32.153: E/SQLiteLog(15050): (14) os_unix.c:30174: (2)        open(/data/data/eu.isdc.cabinCrew/databases/database.sqlite) - 
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050): Failed to open database '/data/data/eu.isdc.cabinCrew/databases/database.sqlite'.
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not   open database
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at eu.isdc.cabinCrew.a.b.c(Unknown Source)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at eu.isdc.cabinCrew.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at eu.isdc.cabinCrew.a.a.<init>(Unknown Source)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at eu.isdc.cabinCrew.a.a.a(Unknown       Source)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at eu.isdc.cabinCrew.activities.TrainingActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
     01-11 14:36:32.183: E/SQLiteDatabase(15050):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     01-11 14:36:32.503: E/SQLiteLog(15050): (1) no such table: airdata
```

It does open the database, but doesn't find that particular table, even if it's there. And this happens only with Jelly Bean. Did anything change with database interaction with this version?

Comment: So what's not working, is the app crashing? If so post the stracktrace of crash

Comment: Ia added some more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is kind of fixed, it still persists but I found that the real problem was lying with showing the data on the UI with an Auto-fit TextView adapter, which didn't work on jelly Bean. 
So I still get the 'Failed to open database' exception, but it works anyway, the databse is read.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assume that databases will always be available at "/data/data/" . Instead you need to getPath() to get the path of the db file.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose so, but that's not the problem, I tried with `myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath();`  and nothing changed. Thing is, the database is read, but partially, so the path is ok